# How can I resolve the occuring ambiguity when using clog for computing the natural logarithm with complex numbers?

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, ambiguous, clog

I have a complex double array `eigenvalues` of which I want to get the natural logarithm of each entry by using `clog`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    qq[i] = clog(eigenvalues[i]);
}
```

I already dropped the `using namespace std;` but am still getting `error: reference to 'clog' is ambiguous`.

How can I make it clear that I want to use the `clog` from `complex.h` and not from `iostream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce this with gcc 7.3 without `using namespace std` but in general all functions from C headers reside in the global namespace. Therefore you should be able to resolve the ambiguity by prefixing clog with `::`:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    qq[i] = ::clog(eigenvalues[i]);
}
```

Comment: Agreed, you must have a `using namesapce std` elsewhere - maybe in an included header?

Comment: This solved it, thanks. Yes, in one header I'm including it was used.